# Slice throw a list using for in python

Tags: python, json

I have the following list which is actually a dictionary coming from a python:

```
{"Age": {"1": 72, "0": 86, "3": 56, "2": 56, "4": 55}, "Weight": {"1": 71, "0": 70, "3": 39, "2": 61, "4": 54}, "Animal": {"1": "Cat", "0": "Dog", "3": "Horse", "2": "Monkey", "4": "mice"}}
```

How can I slice this to get 3 lists?
I want to get something like this:

```
Age = {"1": 72, "0": 86, "3": 56, "2": 56, "4": 55}
Weight =  {"1": 71, "0": 70, "3": 39, "2": 61, "4": 54}
Animal = {"1": "Cat", "0": "Dog", "3": "Horse", "2": "Monkey", "4": "mice"}
```

I know I should use a for like this:

```
for k, v in Age.items():
 print v
```

But how can I do it for 3 lists and how can I assign it the way I want to:
weight = {...}, animal = {...}

Comment: Which lists? The code uses dictionaries.

Comment: this is a dict not list

Comment: `Age = { ...` is not a list. You have a nested dictionary there. Please be specific about the output you desire.

Comment: Iterate over the keys and store the nested dictionary in a separate variable. `for k in x.keys(): x[k]  # store each iteration of this`

Comment: I just saw an old question floating in the 'active' spec of main, concerning this topic, it seems neither you do some researches, nor even you take furtive peeps in the main site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign each required key into your variables:

```
combined = {"Age": {"1": 72, "0": 86, "3": 56, "2": 56, "4": 55}, "Weight": {"1": 71, "0": 70, "3": 39, "2": 61, "4": 54}, "Animal": {"1": "Cat", "0": "Dog", "3": "Horse", "2": "Monkey", "4": "mice"}}

age = combined['Age']
weight = combined['Weight']
animal = combined['Animal']

print age
print weight
print animal
```

Giving you:

```
{'1': 72, '0': 86, '3': 56, '2': 56, '4': 55}
{'1': 71, '0': 70, '3': 39, '2': 61, '4': 54}
{'1': 'Cat', '0': 'Dog', '3': 'Horse', '2': 'Monkey', '4': 'mice'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong naming for the data structure. 
What you are referring is a dict not list. But for the problem mentioned. Below is a solution.

```
input_dict = {"Age": {"1": 72, "0": 86, "3": 56, "2": 56, "4": 55}, "Weight": {"1": 71, "0": 70, "3": 39, "2": 61, "4": 54}, "Animal": {"1": "Cat", "0": "Dog", "3": "Horse", "2": "Monkey", "4": "mice"}}
for k,v  in input_dict.items():
    vars()[k] = v
```

You can print the variable now.

```
print Age
{'1': 72, '0': 86, '3': 56, '2': 56, '4': 55}
print Weight
{'1': 71, '0': 70, '3': 39, '2': 61, '4': 54}
print Animal
{'1': 'Cat', '0': 'Dog', '3': 'Horse', '2': 'Monkey', '4': 'mice'}
```

Modified the answer as per suggestion from  @Eric Duminil

Answer (score 0):

Your data format is really weird and makes iteration and lookup much harder than necessary.

Here's a way to convert it to a simpler data format. It's still a dict of dicts. It should be easier to do iterations and lookups, though:

```
weird_data = {"Age": {"1": 72, "0": 86, "3": 56, "2": 56, "4": 55}, "Weight": {"1": 71, "0": 70, "3": 39, "2": 61, "4": 54}, "Animal": {"1": "Cat", "0": "Dog", "3": "Horse", "2": "Monkey", "4": "mice"}}

data = {name:{
        'id' : int(i),
        'age': weird_data["Age"][i],
        'weight': weird_data["Weight"][i]
    } for i,name in weird_data["Animal"].items()}

print(data)
#{'Cat': {'age': 72, 'id': 1, 'weight': 71},
# 'Dog': {'age': 86, 'id': 0, 'weight': 70},
# 'Horse': {'age': 56, 'id': 3, 'weight': 39},
# 'Monkey': {'age': 56, 'id': 2, 'weight': 61},
# 'mice': {'age': 55, 'id': 4, 'weight': 54}}
```

As an example:

```
>>> list(data)
['Cat', 'Dog', 'Horse', 'Monkey', 'mice']
>>> [data[animal]['age'] for animal in data]
[72, 86, 56, 56, 55]
>>> data['Dog']['weight']
70
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say that the dictionary in your questions be represented by

```
dictionary = {
        "Age": {"1": 72, "0": 86, "3": 56, "2": 56, "4": 55},
        "Weight": {"1": 71, "0": 70, "3": 39, "2": 61, "4": 54},
        "Animal": {"1": "Cat", "0": "Dog", "3": "Horse", "2": "Monkey","4":"mice"}
}
```

You can create a function like this:-

```
def split_dictionary(Age, Weight, Animal):
    return Age, Weight, Animal
```

And then simply call the function like this:-

```
Age, Weight, Animal = split_dictionary(**dictionary)
```